# Unordered list inside nav not present in Opera - all other browser behave normal

Tags: html, html-lists, opera, nav

One of my sites has a horizontal navigation bar which is created using a list. Besides a small bug in Firefox the list looks & works fine by now - except in Opera 11.61. There the list elements won't show up at all! As the list is the site's main navigation it is nested inside a `nav` element. So far my debugging showed that this is where the problem is.

When I remove any background information (like `background-image` or `background-color`) from the `nav` element the list is still invisible - I can see the `body`'s `background-color`.
Also assigning different `z-index` values did nothing. But removing the `nav` element helps - when there is no `nav` the list shows up.

I created a small test case illustrating the problem (remember: Must be opened with Opera.): http://jsfiddle.net/sX5KF/

Do you have any clue why this problem occurs? Is there a fault in my code or is this just something like a bug in Opera? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I found the mistake. Opera displays nothing because I set `content: "";` on the `after`-element. Other browsers seem to ignore it, but not Opera. I set it because I read it is needed, but actually it works even without `content: "";`.

Comment: You didn't have any `:after` in your jsfiddle... You did have a `content:""` property on the main UL though.

Comment: @Sven (about `content: "";`)btw, where did you read it was needed? We are trying to assess if what should be the rules for this case, or if it should be dropped. Other browsers do not support this specific case. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, instead of `after`I meant `last-child`. I read about it on this page (sorry, it is in German): http://www.mediaevent.de/css/css-selektor-first-child-before-after.html. Now that I've read it again I understand that on that page they achieve something different than I needed for my case.